# gzencode in PHP then gunzip in c sharp resulting in lots of whitespace

Tags: c#, gzip, compression

I am passing a large quantity of XML from PHP to C Sharp, so have opted to gzip it. However, the resulting uncompressed string in C Sharp has massive amounts of whitespace at the end

**PHP side**

```
echo base64_encode(gzencode($settings,9));
```

**C Sharp side**

```
    private static string _gzipDecompress(string compressedText)
    {

        byte[] gZipBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gZipBuffer, 0);
            memoryStream.Write(gZipBuffer, 0, gZipBuffer.Length);

            var buffer = new byte[dataLength];

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                gZipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
```

The decompression works fine, but the resulting string is 559903 in length (string.Length) when it should actually be 6629 due to a massive amount of whitespace at the end of the string.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you know the decompression is even working?  It looks like you are getting a four-byte length from the start of the decoded Base-64 data, but then you don't skip those four bytes to start decompressing.  Also why do you think that there's a four-byte length at the start?  The PHP gzencode doesn't prepend such a length.

Comment: The rest of the program parses the decompressed XML fine, so it does seem to be working, but if I write out the XML string to the console its just thousands of lines of whitespace.

To be honest I pulled the code above from the internet and modified it slightly for my needs, I dont really have any concept on what it does. Its not exactly as simple as PHP's gzdecode()!

Comment: Then `GetString` is probably looking for a terminating null, and not finding it for a long time.  Try `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` instead.